# Generate multiple APK from one single project

Tags: android, build, gradle, apk

I'm trying to understand how i can generate multiple APK from one single project.

I'm using gradle and this is my project's three:

[image]

- **ambrogiocore** is the core library module that implements all the common classes and resources.
- **ambrogioremote** is the module that has the :ambrogiocore dependence.

It's work. Now i'm able to generate multiple APK. (just one at the moment)
One apk for each module.

The *problem* is that i need to **manually sync all the AndroidManifest.xml** for every future module that i'll include in my project.

Is this the correct way?
Can i automate this operation?

I took a look at **productFlavor**. Just I don't understand if this tool can help me.

What do you think about?

THANK YOU ALL!

## **SOLUTION**

Finally! I found the same solution proposed by @Kai!

**Flavor is the way!**

This is the best approach for a lots of reasons:

- Single-module project
- You don't need to copy XML files
- **RoboGuice will work like a charm**. (RoboGuice presents some BIG problem on library projects)

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Gradle_Build_Variants_Example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "*one single source core and multiple project that extends "ProductName", "PackageName" and "resources"*" you mean to provide each flavor with unique "ProductName", "PackageName" and "resources", then **yes** it can be done.

To give each flavor its own unique package, set `applicationId` for each of your flavors like so:

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        flavor_1 {
            applicationId = 'com.app.flavor_1'
        }

        flavor_2 {
            applicationId = 'com.app.flavor_2'
        }
    }
}
```

To give each flavor its own app name and resources, simply put them in a flavor's own directory, Gralde will merge a flavor's resources with your base resources to create a complete one.

For more detail on how Gralde flavors work, please see [Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide)

Answer (score 0):

This is my final solution!

- All the common files, manifest and base resources are under ***"src/main"***
- I moved my projects inside ***"src/projects"***
- declared two productFlavor (one per project) specifying ***applicationId*** and ***versionName***
- created two sourceSet (one per project) indicating the specific res folder.

[image]